# Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0 error occur

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

This is my struct

```
struct CommunityListRM: Codable {
    let status       : Bool?
    let communityList: [CommunityList]?
    
    struct CommunityList: Codable {
        var id              : String?
        var user_id         : String?
        var icon            : String?
        var nickname        : String?
        var profile_image   : String?
        var content         : String?
        var image_1_url     : String?
        var image_2_url     : String?
        var image_3_url     : String?
        var image_4_url     : String?
        var image_5_url     : String?
        var image_ratio1    : String?
        var image_ratio2    : String?
        var image_ratio3    : String?
        var image_ratio4    : String?
        var image_ratio5    : String?
        var comment_qty     : String?
        var like_qty        : String?
        var date            : String?
        var created_at      : String?
        var updated_at      : String?
        var like_it         : String?
    }
}
```

I want to insertRows like instagram feeds

```
var posts        : [CommunityListRM.CommunityList] = []

NetworkService().request(.communityList, params, header) { [self] (response: DataResponse<CommunityListRM,AFError>) in
    switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
        if let nComList = data.communityList {

           self.posts.append(contentsOf: nComList)
           print("selfpostcount\(self.posts.count)")
           self.tableview.beginUpdates()
           self.tableview.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.posts.count - 1, section: 0)], with: .none)
           self.tableview.endUpdates()
       }
    }
}
```

If i tried this code error occur

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (10) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Table view: <UITableView: 0x104125c00; frame = (0 0; 414 721); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x281a62b20>; layer = <CALayer: 0x2814a0b40>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {414, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0};

Help me plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `begin-/endUpdates()` is pointless for a single insert/delete/move operation.

---

The error occurs because you are adding multiple items to the array but insert only one row. You have to specify all index paths.

- If `posts` is empty `map` all indices of `posts` to index paths

  ```
  self.posts.append(contentsOf: nComList)
  let indexPaths = self.posts.indices.map{IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}
  self.tableview.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
  ```

  or – as you don't specify any animation – just reload the table view

  ```
  self.posts.append(contentsOf: nComList)
  self.tableview.reloadData()
  ```
- If `posts` is not empty count the items in the array before and after appending the items to get start and end index

  ```
  let startIndex = self.posts.count
  self.posts.append(contentsOf: newArray)
  let endIndex = self.posts.count
  let indexPaths = (startIndex..<endIndex).map{IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}
  self.tableview.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much!! your post is so helpful. I tried, It works!